# dispatch_semaphore_wait not response after signal

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

```
sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

// called by NSOperationQueue
-(void)waitFromUI
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);  //<NSThread: 0x60000007d7c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
    NSLog(@"%ld",dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER));
}

// called by UI Button click
-(void)responseFromUI:(BOOL)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]); //<NSThread: 0x600000060840>{number = 1, name = main}
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
}
```

Refer to the code, the workflow is first `waitFromUI` in NSOperation block, then show a UI by `performSelectorOnMainThread` in this block, then click the button in this UI to call `responseFromUI`.

the function `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is not ended after i call the `dispatch_semaphore_signal`, it waits forever and block my main thread.
 Anybody knows what's the matter with my code.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363936/dispatch-semaphore-t-reuse-what-am-i-missing-here

Comment: @SurajSukale, do you know the mistake of my code?